# Creating memoize for Future values and timeout

Tags: scala

I have the following problem:

I have a API `getSimilarTransactions` which gets a `Transaction`:

```
{
 "name": "zvi",
 "email": "zvi@gmail.com",
 "amount": 100,
...
}
```

And returns a list of transactions that have similar `(name, email)` from the persistence database.
This operation takes `~40seconds` which is **a lot of time**.

I also know that a lot of the API requests are pretty similar (same id, email) , and they're a lot of API requests per minute.

I want to create memorize caching with the following logic:

1. If i did already call the database and got a response for `(id, email)` in the last `30 seconds` return this answer
2. otherwise, make a call to the database and update the cache (call to the database returns `Future[List[Transaction]]`, its also can fail - in that case i do **NOT** want to update the cache with an error.

I want to solve my problem with `memorize`, something as follows, but asynchronously with timeout expiration for cache key

```
def memoize[I,O](f: I => O) = new mutable.HashMap[I, O]() {
    override def apply(x: I) = getOrElseUpdate(x, f(x))
}
```

Database call:

```
transactionsDao.getSimilarTransaction(id: String, email: String): Future[List[Transaction]]
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: (1) keep tuples in the map, second element being the time of update; (2) on `get` check the age of the tuple and discard if more than 30 seconds. (3) don't forget yhat your implementation is not thread safe. You need to synchronize. Mutable state is a bitch. You are probably better off using some standard cache library, like ehCache or Guava or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I wrote this from off the top of my head, YMMV, etc.

Assuming that you have some timer facility, called `someTimer` in the code below, you should be able to do something equivalent of:

```scala
    class Cache[K, V] {
      private final val cached = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[K, Promise[V]]()
      def get(key: K, orCreate: => Future[V]): Future[V] =
        cached.get(key) match {
          case null =>
            val p = Promise[V]()
            cached.putIfAbsent(key, p) match {
              case null =>
                p.completeWith(orCreate).future.andThen({ case _ => someTimer.after(someTime, () => cached.remove(key, p))})(ExecutionContext.parasitic)
              case existing =>
                existing.future
            }
          case existing =>
            existing.future
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```scala
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  val cache = new Cache[String, Int]

  val f, e = cache.get("foo", Future((scala.math.random() * 1000).toInt))
  f.onComplete(println)
  e.onComplete(println)
```

Prints:

Success(720)

Success(720)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ScalaCache](https://cb372.github.io/scalacache/) library which has mode for `Future`: https://cb372.github.io/scalacache/docs/modes.html#future-mode:

```
import scalacache.modes.scalaFuture._
import scalacache.caffeine.CaffeineCache // in memory cache

implicit val transactionCache: Cache[List[Transaction]] = CaffeineCache[List[Transaction]]

def getTransactions(id: String, email: String) = memoizeF[Future, List[Transaction]](Some(10.seconds)){
    callToDatabase(id, Email)
}
```

See for more details: https://cb372.github.io/scalacache/docs/memoization.html

Comment: @ZviMints Implement custom cache? Well most likely, please, take a look at Cache trait, but I'm pretty sure that existing bindings will cover bigger part of use cases.